# Is a double right caret syntax >> valid MySQL for mysqldump

Tags: mysql

I came across code that uses double >> syntax together with mysqldump.  I'm wondering if this is valid mysqldump syntax.  I did some google searches but wasn't able to find anything, so I'm thinking it's a typo:

`mysqldump -h *** -u *** -p *** --single-transaction --no-data database_name table_name >> file_name`

Can someone please confirm that it's invalid syntax or otherwise explain how `>>` works compared to just the ordinary `>` that I would expect to see here?

Comment: that's is definitely an typo. I had never seen that syntax. I wonder if this really works.

Comment: @ChristianFelix It's not necessarily a typo. `>`, `>>`, `2>` and `&>` are all valid redirection directives. This script is dumping a single table, so it's possible that there were other tables being dumped into that file as well. `>>` *appends* to the given file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a typo. You're right, that's not MySQL or mysqldump syntax.  mysqldump utility writes output to `STDOUT`.

The `>>` is syntax for the shell.

That redirects `STDOUT` to *append* to the specified file_name.

As a demonstration, consider:

```
echo "fee"  >  /tmp/mytest
echo "fi"   >> /tmp/mytest
echo "fo"   >> /tmp/mytest
echo "fum"  >> /tmp/mytest
cat /tmp/mytest
```

Comment: It's good for accumulating the result of multiple commands into one file.